# Настройки SharedPreferences в отдельный класс

Tags: android

Добрый день. Я самостоятельно учу программирование. Ребята помогите разобраться, как правильно метод вынести в отдельный класс.  Есть метод в главной `Activity`, который сохраняет `String` в настройках `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void menuTobe() {
    listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor77 = mySettings1.edit();
    editor77.putString(Tobe_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
    editor77.apply();
    Log.d("", "Сохраненный Tobe_ArrayList:" + Arrayl + listStr);
    if (mySettings1.contains(Tobe_ArrayList)) {// если сохранен Tobe_ArrayList
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
        editor.remove("Tobe_ArrayList"); // удаляем Tobe_ArrayList
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Вот я пытаюсь его написать в отдельном классе.

```
public class SaveQuestions {
    // обьявление переменных
    SharedPreferences mySettings1;
    Activity a;

    String listStr;
    ArrayList<Integer> Arrayl;

    public SaveQuestions(Activity act) {
        a = act;// контекст через конструктор
        mySettings1 = act.getSharedPreferences(SPFILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public String menuTobe() {
        Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();
        listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor77 = mySettings1.edit();
        editor77.putString(Tobe_ArrayList, listStr);// cохраняем Arrayl в строке в SharedPreferences
        editor77.apply();
        Log.d("", "Сохраненный Tobe_ArrayList:" + Arrayl + listStr);
        if (mySettings1.contains(Tobe_ArrayList)) {// если сохранен Tobe_ArrayList
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mySettings1.edit();
            editor.remove("Tobe_ArrayList"); // удаляем Tobe_ArrayList
            editor.apply();
        }
        return listStr;
   }
}
```

Обращаюсь к нему в главной активити так:

```
SaveQuestions sv = new SaveQuestions(this);
sv. menuTobe();
```

В главной активити метод `menuTobe()` сохраняет строку в `SharedPreferences`, а в отдельном классе нет

Comment: Cори, не могу редактировать сообщение. Вообщем. В главной активити метод menuTobe() сохраняет строку в SharedPreferences, а в отдельном классе нет.

Comment: Никогда не передавайте ссылку на активити!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/144921)

Comment: Если какой-то из ответов привёл вас к решению, отметьте его как верный (галочка слева от ответа).

Comment: Кстати, почему не можете редактировать? Жмите кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 4):

```
Arrayl = new ArrayList<>();
listStr = new Gson().toJson(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrayl));// сохраняю Arrayl в строку
```

А ничего, что на момент инициализации `listStr`, ваш `Arrayl` девственно пуст?